# Devexpress Add a control to Layout panel

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

i made a documentpanel and added it to a documetgroup, i created a Gridcontrol and have no idea on how to add it to the panel i created

```
 Dim tab As New DocumentPanel
  tab.Name = "name"
  Dim grid As New DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl
'how to add the grid to the tab?!
  DocumentGroup.Items.Add(tab)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
tab.Content = grid
```